# How to sum data after remove duplicate ($addToSet) mongoose aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, aggregate

i have struggle to sum value after remove duplicate in mongoose. i have data like this:

```
{
            "_id": "6006c7f624d9e1364051b0aa",
            "paidFrom": "5fec1b5d124c58c6ddacfd02",
            "amount": 234,
        },
        {
            "_id": "600e63f2545087cbddfe370a",
            "paidFrom": "5fec1b5d124c58c6ddacfd02",
            "amount": 25000,
        },
        {
            "_id": "600e7c16545087cbddfe370b",
            "paidFrom": "5ff56473609e930518cb7b67",
            "amount": 5000,

        },
```

i want to remove duplicate data using aggregation, i want to sum by the same paid from value.

this is my code:

```
const dataAP = await AccountPayment.aggregate([
      { 
          $match: filterDate
      },
      {
        $group: {
            _id:  null,
            paidFrom: {
              "$addToSet" : "$paidFrom",
            },
            amount: {$sum: "$amount"}
        }
    },
    ], 
      function (err, res)
      {
          if (err) {} 
            console.log(err)
      });
```

but that code give me result:

```
"status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": null,
            "paidFrom": [
                "5ff56473609e930518cb7b67",
                "5fec1b5d124c58c6ddacfd02",
                "5ff54212609e930518cb7b65"
            ],
            "amount": 60234
        }
    ]
}
```

my expected result is:

```
"status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": null,
            "paidFrom": [
                "5ff56473609e930518cb7b67",
            ],
            "amount": 20000
        },
{
            "_id": null,
            "paidFrom": [
                "5fec1b5d124c58c6ddacfd02",
            ],
            "amount": 20000
        },
{
            "_id": null,
            "paidFrom": [
                "5ff54212609e930518cb7b65",
            ],
            "amount": 20234
        },
    ]


}
```

i want amount is sum by duplicate value, so i can calculate the duplicate value. can someone tell me whats wrong? thanks

Comment: Why `paidFrom` need to be an array? If i understand the question correctly, it always has only one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to group by `paidFrom` id and sum amount, it will group duplicate documents and sum total `amount`

```
const dataAP = await AccountPayment.aggregate([
  { $match: filterDate },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$paidFrom",
      amount: { $sum: "$amount" }
    }
  }
], 
function (err, res) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A8XL2q2SmoQ)